# adding multiple files in folder and zipping in loop

Tags: fasta, ncbi

Through fasterq-dump, I am generating 2 files in 1 run of loop. I want to club these two files (A_1.fastq & A_2.fastq) in one folder and zip the it.

```
cat SRR_Acc_List.txt | while read i ; do  fasterq-dump ${i} --split-files -v --skip-technical  -e 15 ; for j in 2 ; do   gzip ${i}_j.fastq  ; done; done
cat SRR_Acc_List.txt | while read i ; do  fasterq-dump ${i} --split-files -v --skip-technical  -e 15 ; for(j = 1;j<2;j++) ; do   gzip ${i}_j.fastq  ; done; done

cat SRR_Acc_List.txt | while read i ; do  fasterq-dump ${i} --split-files -v --skip-technical  -e 15 ; for j in 1 2 ; do   gzip ${i}_${j}.fastq  ; done; done

cat SRR_Acc_List.txt | while read i ; do  fasterq-dump ${i} --split-files -v --skip-technical  -e 15 ; for j in 2 ; do   gzip ${i}_${j}.fastq  ; done; done
cat SRR_Acc_List.txt | while read i ; do  fasterq-dump ${i} --split-files -v --skip-technical  -e 15 | mkdir {i} | for j in i; do   gzip ${i}  ; done; done

cat SRR_Acc_List.txt | while read i ; do  fasterq-dump ${i} --split-files -v --skip-technical  -e 15 | mkdir ${i} ; for j in i; do   gzip ${i}  ; done; done
cat SRR_Acc_List.txt | while read i ; do  fasterq-dump ${i} --split-files -v --skip-technical  -e 15 ; mkdir ${i} ; mv ${i}_*.fastq "${i}"; for j in i ; do gzip ${i} ; done;done

cat SRR_Acc_List.txt | while read i ; do  fasterq-dump ${i} --split-files -v --skip-technical  -e 15 ; mkdir ${i} ; mv ${i}_*.fastq "${i}";done; for j in i ; do zip ${i} ; done

cat SRR_Acc_List.txt | while read i ; do  fasterq-dump ${i} --split-files -v --skip-technical  -e 15 ; mkdir ${i} ; mv ${i}_*.fastq "${i}" ;  zip ${i} ; done

cat SRR_Acc_List.txt | while read i ; do  fasterq-dump ${i} --split-files -v --skip-technical  -e 15 ; mkdir ${i} ; mv ${i}_*.fastq "${i}" ; tar -cv ${i} | gzip > ${i}.tar.gz ; done
```

None of them is working.

Comment: Try your code on one set of FQs and use a loop only after that set gets processed successfully. Also, why pipe tar to gzip when you can simply do `tar -czf archive.tar.gz files_to_archive`?